# could not find nats-0.4.22.beta.8 in any of the sources

Tags: cloud-foundry

When executing 'bash < <(curl -s -k -B https://raw.github.com/cloudfoundry/vcap/master/dev_setup/bin/vcap_dev_setup)' to install cloudfoundry, I got this error: could not find nats-0.4.22.beta.8 in any of the sources.

Answer (score 1):

When installing VCAP, this typically indicates a networking or proxy issue. Are you still seeing the error? If so, I recommend posting the full output of the error to the vcap-dev google group at https://groups.google.com/a/cloudfoundry.org/group/vcap-dev/topics